# RSASSA-PSS-SIGN modBits size

Tags: rsa, tls

In RFC 8017 `modBits` is the length in bits of the RSA modulus `n`
I am using 2048 RSA key
`modBits` = 2048?
`modBits` = 2048 % `n`?
lets say `n` = 10 decimal = 1010 binary
then `modBits` = 4?
in my 2048 RSA key DER file `n` uses 257 bytes
then `modBits` = 257 *8 ?
which `modBits` = ... is true?

Comment: did you convert the PEM to DER to see 257 bytes? In short, how you get this value?

Comment: yes in DER format

Comment: Did you count the leading zero? Or did you use an online converter?

Comment: the DER file says `n` uses 257 bytes and yes `n` has a 00 in the left most byte

Comment: Could you post your public key?

Comment: its just the RSAPrivateKey ::= SEQUENCE encoded in DER, I think posting the file data adds anything but noise to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- $\text{modBits}$ is the length of RSA modulus $n$ for example if you have 17 as RSA modulus than it has $\texttt{10001}$ as base two representation and has $\text{modBits} = 5$
- If you generate a modulus $n$ which is 2048-bit than the $\text{modBits} = 2048$. Keep in mind that, we say a number $n$ is 2048-bit when it is between $2^{2047} \leq n \leq 2^{2048}-1$

> lets say n = 10 decimal = 1010 binary
>   then modBits = 4?

Yes 4.

> in my 2048 RSA key PEM file n uses 257 bytes
>   then modBits = 257 *8 ?

The leading `00` is coming from ASN.1 encoding of integers. Therefore you have 256-byte key.

> which one is the value of modBits?

8*256

Comment: this question `which one is the value of modBits?` is referring to which of all modBits = ? is the true one, not which DER file data defines `n`

Comment: Isn't clear? One byte is 00, this is part of the encoding.

Comment: my question shows different values that `modBits` can have based on the RFC definition, then at the end asks which value is true, in your answer `modBits = 8*256 if n uses 256 bytes` and `modBits = 4 if n = 10` but `modBits = 8*256 if n uses 256 bytes` is not true because the exact value of `n` isn't known, only if you know the exact value of `n` you can know `modBits`

Comment: That is why I've asked your file.

Comment: its not needed and you should edit your answer, `modBits = 8*256` is not true

Comment: Are you talking about that when you run keygen for 2048-bit key for RSA it can create 2047?

Comment: @porente If you know it all so well, then why post a question? Kelalaka is right, to show how the encoded key is structured, you should post an example private key that contains the modulus.

Comment: his answer has a contradiction and at the same time made it clear which one was the right answer to my question, the best answers describe the idea with as little words as possible, adding the example public key is absolutely not necessary to describe the idea, so the best answer to my question would be `if n = 17 decimal = 10001 binary then modBits = 5`